# Ad Campaign on Sakila Database

Tags: mysql, sql

Can Someone help me with the **SQL** code for:

Suppose you are running an advertising campaign in Canada for which you need the `film_ids` and titles of all the films released in Canada. List the films in the alphabetical order of their titles.

I tried something but I am not able to figure it out.

```
SELECT film_id, title 
FROM film

WHERE COUNTRY IN (SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRY
INNER JOIN FILM USING (FILM_ID)
INNER JOIN INVENTORY USING (STORE_ID)
INNER JOIN STORE USING (ADDRESS_ID)
INNER JOIN ADDRESS USING (CITY_ID)
INNER JOIN CITY USING (COUNTRY_ID)
WHERE COUNTRY = ('Canada'))

ORDER BY Title;
```

I am getting this error.

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 3: Unknown column 'FILM_ID' in 'from
> clause'

**Note:** Data for only the required tables has been added for every question. I have to determine which tables are to be used for solving this question.

[Sample expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzjDr.png)

[Sakila Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HQ22.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from here:

```
SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRY
 INNER JOIN FILM USING (FILM_ID)
```

`Country` does not have a `film_id` column, so it does not work. That said, you can simplify your query a little bit to get the results you need:

```
SELECT f.film_id, f.title 
  FROM Film f INNER JOIN Inventory inv ON f.film_id = inv.film_id
              INNER JOIN Store sto ON inv.store_id = sto.store_id
              INNER JOIN Address addr ON sto.address_id = addr.address_id
              INNER JOIN City c ON addr.city_id = c.city_id 
              INNER JOIN Country co ON c.country_id = co.country_id 
 WHERE co.country = 'Canada'
 ORDER BY f.title, f.film_id;
```

The subquery is unnecessary and references a column that does not exist in the `Film` table.

Comment: For some reason the table names on dbfiddle should not contain capitals. When changing all table names to lowercase, here is the [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&sample=sakila&fiddle=2c91ca3276b7e3553c879cf92bf9394c)

Answer (score 0):

```
select Film_id, Title
    from film
inner join inventory
    using (film_id)
inner join store
    using (store_id)
inner join address
    using (address_id)
inner join city
    using (city_id)
inner join country
    using (country_id)
where country = 'Canada'
group by film_id, title
order by title;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select Film_id, Title
from film
inner join inventory
using (film_id)
inner join store
using (store_id)
inner join address
using (address_id)
inner join city
using (city_id)
inner join country
using (country_id)
where country = 'Canada'
group by film_id, title
order by title;
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why this request fix the issue, such as what did you change ?